# Проблема с кодировкой при Ajax-запросе

Tags: javascript, jquery, кодировка

Всем добрый день.
Есть такой несложный код:

```
$('select[name="course-111"]').change(function() {
$.get(
    "/ajax.php?action=get_price&course_name=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()),
    function(e) {
        $('input[name="price-111"]').val(e)
    }
), $('select[name="course-date-111"]').load("/ajax.php?action=get_date&course_id=" + window.course_id + "&course_name=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val()))
```

});

Он вытягивает список страниц из категории и выдает в форме записи обычный всплывающий селектор с списком доступных курсов.
Все работает на WordPress

В какой-то момент, данный список в форме обратной связи стал отображаться знаками вопросов (???? ????, вместо заголовка). Даже если заголовок делать не на русском, все равно кодировка сбита.

Может ли кто-то посоветовать, что с этим делать? Где может быть ошибка? В базе данных WP, в кодировке страниц шаблонов или еще где-то?

Comment: Проверьте стоит ли в конфиге `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

Comment: Проверил, стоит.. 41 строчка (скорее всего дефолтный полностью конфиг).

Comment: Также задавал кодировку через htaccess - реакции не было.
Сейчас пытаюсь восстановить хронологически, когда появилась проблема.. теоретически, 10 числа ВП обновился до новой версии (сам, как говорят хозяева), может быть там что-то затерлось.

Comment: @ysilence пробовали определить кодировку в ajax.php?

Comment: О таком не знал. Там стоит:
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Подозреваю - это верная запись?

Comment: Я даже не знаю как уточнить больше проблему.. Вот в данном куске, все логично, кажется, но не работает:

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); include('wp-config.php');
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
if($_GET['action'] == 'get_courses') {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_type='nlp' OR post_type='psihologiya' OR post_type='kommunikaciya') AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY ID");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['post_title']."' ".($_GET['course_id']==$row['ID']?'selected="selected"':NULL).">".$row['post_title']."</option>";
    }
}`

Comment: Я справился с проблемой. В ajax.php сразу после обращения к базе данных прописал строку:
`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

И обновил кеш браузера. Эта строка помогла.